# Is the total damage dealt from a source effectively parceled out across any number of assets?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

When damage (or horror) is dealt, do I effectively take those N units of damage and get to spread them out however I like as long as the distribution doesn't exceed the remaining health for any particular asset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is detailed in the Rules Reference Guide (relevant section below, from page 7 under "Dealing Damage/Horror"), but the short answer is that damage is allocated in two steps - first it is *assigned* and then it is *applied*. The only restriction for assigning damage is that you cannot overload it (so if you have an ally who can take 1 sanity and 1 damage, you cannot put a 3 sanity tokens on it).

But yes, otherwise, damage or horror can be split among your investigator and any assets as you deem fit.

> When an investigator or enemy is dealt damage and/or horror,
> follow these steps, in order:
>
> 1. Assign Damage/Horror: Determine the amount of damage and/or horror being dealt. Place damage and/or horror tokens equal to the amount of
>    damage and horror being dealt next to the cards that will be taking
>    the damage/horror.
> 2. Apply Damage/Horror: Any assigned damage/ horror that has not been prevented is now placed on each card to which it has been assigned,
>    simultaneously. If no damage/horror is applied in this step, no
>    damage/horror has been successfully dealt.